# Unable to make an mysql query

Tags: sql, mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    tr.object_id,tt.taxonomy, im . * 
FROM
    term_relationships AS tr
        INNER JOIN term_taxonomy AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id 
        INNER JOIN image AS im ON tr.object_id = im.ID
```

In the above query I want it not to display the results I get from `tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id` if it's equal to "cat".

Comment: Which field would be equal to "cat"? Please provide some sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    tr.object_id,tt.taxonomy, im . * 
FROM
    term_relationships AS tr
        INNER JOIN term_taxonomy AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id 
        INNER JOIN image AS im ON tr.object_id = im.ID
WHERE taxonomy != 'cat'
```